# How to build a variadic title for a plot with expression, paste, bquote, and/or substitute?

Tags: r, eval, lazy-evaluation, variadic-functions, variadic

For a regression plot, I would like the title to be the following:

```
hat(y) = mx + b
F_{df1,df2} = Fval, p = pval
R^2 = rval
```

where `m` and `b` and `df1` and `df2` and `Fval` and `pval` and `rval` are variadically populated.

I can grab all of the values for these variables and it seems as if `(.df1)` is somehow how I create them within the expression loop, see https://astrostatistics.psu.edu/su07/R/html/grDevices/html/plotmath.html

```
m = 3;
b = 5;
df1 = 1;
df2 = 98;
Fval = 1.0189e+32; # big
pval = 0.9998;
rval = 0.86;
```

I want to build a variable `myMain` that I can place into a plot as the main title.  The three lines would be separated by a "\n" new line.

With `paste0`, not a problem:

```
myMain = paste0(
    "y = ", round(m, 3), "x + ", round(b, 3), "\n", 
    "F(",df1,df2,") = ", Fval, ", p = ",pval, "\n",
    "R^2 = ", rval);
```

But I would like superscript/subscript on the F and R^2, and also like the option of italicizing F, p, and R^2.

I am looking for a variadic solution as this is one class of problems.  At other times, I may need "chemistry" symbols and the like.  The goal would be to create a variable that could be used in the "title" or a "label" or a "legend" or elsewhere.

https://astrostatistics.psu.edu/su07/R/html/grDevices/html/plotmath.html

This is the best reference, discussing `expression` and `bquote` and `substitute` and `mtext` and `plain` and so on.

How can I wrap this into a generic function

(1) where I have a template:

```
hat(y) = mx + b
F_{df1,df2} = Fval, p = pval
R^2 = rval
```

(2) I have a list of values to "replace":

```
m = 3;
b = 5;
df1 = 1;
df2 = 98;
Fval = 1.0189e+32; # big
pval = 0.9998;
rval = 0.86;
```

(3) And it maintains the nice `expression` format?

Doing 1/2 are straight-forward, this last subelement of the problem is where I am struggling. I can post the final three stage solution, with a little help on step 3.

Comment: You might be interested in the `latex2exp` package. As far as a variadic function, I think you're better off simply writing expressions by hand when you need them. Something like `sprintf` for math sounds nice, but I think in practice it would be almost as much trouble to use as just writing the expressions. And it would be very difficult to write such a function, to boot.

Answer (score 0):

We could use `atop` with `bquote`

```
space <- strrep(' ', 40)
space2 <- strrep(' ', 43)
plot(1, 1, main = bquote(atop(atop(y==~.(round(m, 3))*'x + '~.(b)*.(space)*phantom(),
       'F('*.(df1)*','*.(df2)*') = '~.(Fval)~', p = '*.(pval)*phantom()),        
       scriptstyle(R^2 ==.(rval)*.(space2)))))
```

-output

[image]

Comment: Nice start.  I had the R^2, but also `hat(y)` which in latex would be `\hat{y}` and `F_{df1,df2}` which would be subscript.  Hence a need for some variadics.